# Web Scraping News Articles

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am having issues web scraping news article titles and article descriptions from the following website: https://www.hrdive.com/. The coding that I tried did not work. Can someone help me fix this coding in order for it to work?

```
   for i in data.xpath("//li[@class='row feed__item']"):
   title= i.xpath('//h3/a/text()')
   article = i.xpath('//p[@class="feed__description"]/text()')
   print(title, article)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "having issues" and "did not work"?

Comment: When I use this form of coding, it just gives me blank parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are targeting is still nested in several tags, `div > h3 > a`, so you need to use `//` to find it.

```
for i in data.xpath("//li[@class='row feed__item']"):
   title = i.xpath('//h3/a/text()')
   article = i.xpath('//p[@class='feed__description']/text()')
   print(title, article)
```

Notice the double slash `//` at the beginning

**TIP:**

You can test your xpath in the browser console, for example, in your case, you can go to https://www.hrdive.com/ and inspect/go to console and use `$x`:

```
$x("//li[@class='row feed__item']//p[@class='feed__description']/text()")

// or

$x("//li[@class='row feed__item']//p[@class='feed__description']")[0].innerText
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I just have to eliminate the spacing.

Comment: @TimothyJefferson glad it worked, I would appreciate it much if you mark it as an answer :)

Comment: @TimothyJefferson I think you just have to click the arrow up, I haven't posted a question in SO so I really don't know how, lol

Comment: I clicked the arrow up, but I think it will only show once 5 people vote it up.

Comment: @TimothyJefferson I just found this one https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, if doesn't work, never mind :D

Comment: I just checked it as an answer.

Comment: Article actually did not work when put in the coding. Plus, there is the '\n spacing issue.

Comment: with regards to the `\n`, you can just `.strip()` the string.  Are you sure you have the exact xpath as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I put the exact same xpath as you suggested.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the updated xpath here, also I added a TIP on my answer, you may want to try it to debug

Comment: I just posted the updated version of my coding. I was just trying to get a preview of the article and not the whole entire article. I might just get the article title instead.